# Non public Api Usage

Tags: ios, api, xamarin.forms

I want to upload an iOS app using Webview that is rejected from app store connect.

> The app references non-public selectors in myapp.iOS:
>   `applicationWillTerminate`, `setOrientation:animated:`,
>   `terminateWithSuccess`. If method names in your source code match the
>   private Apple APIs listed above.

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: have you created your own methods using any of above names?

Comment: Rename your methods if possible

Comment: This is a nopcommerce 3.8 based project.I have no idea what methods is used in and I using webview for creating app using Single view app(iOS app)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have Test Cloud enabled for your app.

Test Cloud uses the Calabash assembly.

> The Calabash assembly makes uses of non-public Apple API's which will
>   cause apps to be rejected by the App Store. However, the Xamarin.iOS
>   linker will remove the Calabash assembly from the final IPA if it
>   isn't explicitly referenced from code.

Xamarin.Calabash.Start() should be included in AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching inside a conditional such as:

```
#if ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD
// requires Xamarin Test Cloud Agent
Xamarin.Calabash.Start();
#endif
```

...with the ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD variable included as a compiler variable debug builds but not release.  This will cause the Calabash assembly to be removed from app bundle on release builds.

Or just remove Test Cloud altogether if you don't need it.

Instructions under **iOS Application Project** here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/uitest-and-test-cloud?tabs=vswin#adding-uitest-support-to-xamarinforms-apps